# check for value in list of Pandas data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe data that looks like this

```
    MED1    MED2    MED3    MED4    MED5
0   60735   24355   33843   16475   9995
1   10126   5789    17165   90000   90000
2   5789    19675   30553   90000   90000
3   60735   17865   34495   90000   90000
4   19675   5810    90000   90000   90000
```

​I want to create a new bool column "med" that has True/False based on  ​60735 in the columns MED1...MED5
I am trying this and am not sure how to make it work.

```
DF['med'] = (60735 in [DF['MED1'], DF['MED2']])

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

MED1..MED5 represent drugs being taken by a patient at a hospital visit.
I have a list of about 20 drugs for which I need to know if the patien was taking them. Each drug is coded with a number but has a name. A nice solution would look something like (below) but how do I do this with pandas.

```
drugs = {'drug1':60735, 'drug2':5789}  
for n in drugs.keys():
    DF[n] = drugs[n] in DF[['MED1', 'MED2', 'MED3', 'MED4', 'MED5']]
```

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. You want to have True when MED1 = 60735 and False otherwise?

Comment: oops, should be MED1 and MED2, fixed now.

Comment: just in the first two columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Mai's answer will of course work - it may be a bit more standard to write it like this, with the `|` operator.

```
df['med'] = (df['MED1'] == 60735) | (df['MED1'] == 60735)
```

If you want to check for a value in all (or many) columns, you could also use `isin` as below.  The `isin` checks whether the value in the list is in each cell, and the `any(1)` returns True if any element in each row is True.

```
df['med'] = df.isin([60735]).any(1)
```

Edit:
Based on your edited question, would this work?

```
for n in drugs:
    df[n] = df[['MED1','MED2','MED3','MED4','MED5']].isin([drugs[n]]).any(1)
```

Comment: Is there no way to slice the row based on column names and get the values? I have added to the question to better explain what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am still confused. But part of what you want may be this:

```
import numpy as np
DF['med'] = np.logical_or(DF['MED1'] == 60735, DF['MED2'] == 60735)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few `%timeit` comparisons of some methods to return bools from a dataframe column.

```
In [2]: %timeit df['med'] = [bool(x) if int(60735) in x else False for x in enumerate(df['MED1'])]
1000 loops, best of 3: 379 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit df['med'] = (df['MED1'] == 60735)
1000 loops, best of 3: 649 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit df['med'] = df['MED1'].isin([60735])
1000 loops, best of 3: 404 µs per loop
```